# Como enviar um arquivo para o google drive pelo meu aplicativo Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Como posso fazer para enviar um arquivo para o Google drive pelo meu aplicativo Android, estou fazendo um aplicativo no Android Studio e preciso de uma API para enviar arquivos para o google drive

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro recomendo que leia e entenda toda a documentação

Comment: Espero que um desses links ajude em algo [android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk) https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Chamando o intent de compartilhamento de arquivos, o Drive vai estar lá disponível.